# Weblogic Jacoco connection error wrong version

Tags: maven, weblogic, jacoco

I am trying to retrieve coverage dump from weblogic server using maven project.

after running mvn I am getting:

```
  Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:report (jacoco-report) on project jacocotest: An error has occurred in JaCoCo report generation. Error while creating report: Cannot read execution data version 0x1006. This version of JaCoCo uses execution data version 0x1007. -> [Help 1]
```

and in weblogic log:

```
org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.data.IncompatibleExecDataVersionException: Cannot read execution data version 0x1006. This version of JaCoCo uses execution data version 0x1007.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readHeader(ExecutionDataReader.java:129)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readBlock(ExecutionDataReader.java:109)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.runtime.RemoteControlReader.readBlock(RemoteControlReader.java:47)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read(ExecutionDataReader.java:92)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.output.TcpConnection.run(TcpConnection.java:59)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.output.TcpServerOutput$1.run(TcpServerOutput.java:63)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

in pom I have:

```
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>               
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
```

and agent jar,

```
META-INF\Manifest.mf  
Implementation-Version: 0.7.7.201606060606
```

Answer (score 1):

"0x1006" is the version of data that was produced by JaCoCo versions 0.5.0 - 0.7.4. So check carefully that you don't execute WebLogic Server with an old version of JaCoCo, i.e. what is used in `-javaagent` parameter for `java` for start of WebLogic Server.